# Capybara: How to set cookie before navigation / loading page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

How can I set a cookie before navigation with Capybara? The following code raises an exception:

```rb
page.driver.browser.manage.add_cookie(
  name: "name",
  value: "value",
  path: "/",
)
```

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidCookieDomainError:
       invalid cookie domain
         (Session info: headless chrome=98.0.4758.109)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Selenium Webdriver support sending Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP) commands from the driver (this is possible with other drivers like [Cuprite](https://github.com/rubycdp/cuprite) too).

Turns out the CDP [`Network.setCookie`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setCookie) command allows one to specify a domain – allowing you to set cookies before navigating to a site.

Here's a Capybara + Selenium Webdriver example:

```rb
page.driver.browser.execute_cdp(
  "Network.setCookie",
  domain: "example.com",
  name: "name",
  value: "value",
  path: "/",
)
```